# How to get facebook access token using login dialog without login status

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm using facebook login diaglog to get an access token.
The users enter their id/password credentials and my app gets an access token for that user.
That's great.

The problem is as below.

After that, when the user opens web browser and visits www.facebook.com, the user was already logged in. That makes sense because the user filled out their credentials previously.

However, I don't want this. I just need access token for the user not login session in the browser.

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: That is not possible – it is _by design_, OAuth simply works that way – the user has to login to their login provider (here: Facebook) in order to confirm their identity. You can however [log the user out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) of your app _and_ Facebook via API – but that will invalidate a short-lived access token, so you would have to extend it server-side first. (Then you still have an access token to make API calls, but technically the user will not be logged in to your app any more.)

Comment: I hoped that there was a way to get an access token without making the user logged in. However, I could find any document in facebook. I had also thought about logout API using access token. Thank you for your comment. It helped me.